# C++ console ncurses project - QtCreator doesn't show any output in xterm neither in console

Tags: c++, qt-creator, ncurses

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();

    addstr("Hello world");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

This basic application doesn't show any output when building and running in QtCreator 2.8.0.

When i run previously compiled in QtCreator program in separate terminal window, then it works fine. But when i run it under QtCreator (Ctrl-R or press "Run" button), then i see empty xterm window and no output. I guess this is somehow related with `qtcreator_process_stub`, which entitles that empty xterm window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

In Project settings -> Environment -> **TERM** variable should be set to sane value like `xterm`

By default it was set to `dumb`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
addstr("Hello world");
```

with

```
printw("Hello World !!!");
```

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078001/building-helloworld-c-program-in-linux-with-ncurses)

Comment: Same effect, empty xterm screen